# after using chntpw, user doesn't belong to a group

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I used chntpw to promote a normal user to administrator.
then I wanted to reverte it to normal user, but windows complains.
it says: SYSTEM ERROR (can't remember the number), the user doesn't belong to a group or something similar. I can't delete that user from administrator group, nor delete it at all.
Do you know where to touch the registry to correct.
The operating system is windows 7